# sed add different lines in different files

Tags: sed, automator

I'm trying to find a way to run multiple sed commands that adds lines to the start of different files (on Mac OS).

This works when run from terminal.

```
sed -i '' '1i\
\\version \"2.19.65\"\
\\language \"english\"\
\\include \"dynamics-defs.ily\"\
altosaxINotes = \\transpose c ef {\
\\relative c {\
' altosaxI.ily
```

But I want to add slightly different text on a different file:

```
sed -i '' '1i\
\\version \"2.19.65\"\
\\language \"english\"\
\\include \"dynamics-defs.ily\"\
altosaxIINotes = \\transpose c ef {\
\\relative c {\
' altosaxII.ily
```

I have about 30 or 40 of these to run, all slightly different. Is it possible to combine them all into one terminal command, or perhaps use Mac's automator, or maybe a better solution?

Comment: Better in what sense? You could write a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
# create a function f with one parameter
f(){ cat <<! >tempFile && sed -i '1e cat tempFile' ${1}.ily; }
\\version "2.19.65"
\\language "english"
\\include "dynamics-defs.ily"
${1}Notes = \\transpose c ef {
\\relative c {
!
# call the function
f altosaxI
```

The function f can then be included in a for-loop or a script.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I guess my original question wasn't clear enough. Each of my sed codes works individually. I was wondering how I can run 40 such codes in a row without me having to run each individually.

Comment: @CraigDabelstein In the above example each sed script uses the parameter to replace and is also the name of the file being operated on. You can write a script to call the function as many times as you have files to change and/or use a loop with the changes listed in a data file.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to get this script to work but it gives me an "unterminated substitute pattern" error.

Comment: @CraigDabelstein the above sed commands do not include any substitutions (the tempFile is prepended to the original file). Perhaps you have made an error copying the commands?